# Sphinx4 helloworld indexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, sphinx4

i'm running the HelloWorld code give by sphinx.
It starts and waits for me to say something in the mic, but when i start speaking it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 110, Size: 110
    at java.util.SubList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.SubList.get(Unknown Source)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.scorer.ScoreableJob.getFirst(ThreadedAcousticScorer.java:516)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.scorer.ThreadedAcousticScorer.scoreScoreables(ThreadedAcousticScorer.java:310)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.scorer.ThreadedAcousticScorer.calculateScores(ThreadedAcousticScorer.java:276)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.scoreTokens(SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:340)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.recognize(SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:261)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.recognize(SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:229)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.Decoder.decode(Decoder.java:94)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.recognize(Recognizer.java:116)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.recognize(Recognizer.java:135)
    at demo.sphinx.helloworld.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:72)
```

I did add heap memeory to the jvm.
Anyone knows what's this error about?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Recent sphinx4 does not have helloworld demo, you need to try th etutorial http://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialsphinx4